# Adding hours to a String containing 00:00:00

Tags: java, string, date, converters

I am going to send the dateTime variable to an API which requires a String with the time and date in it. But I noticed that there is a time difference, because when I send that variable, it ends up with two hours added on it. So I need to add 2 hours to the time variable.

I tried splitting the time variable, parsed the first element to an int and added 2, and then formatted to a String and so forth, but this seems extremely unnecessarily long. Is there any easier way? I've tried to figure out how to work with time objects and setting the date and time, but I only know how to set to the current time, which I do not want to do. The code below contains the values needed.

```
String date = "2019-05-09";
String time = "10:00:00";
String dateTime = (date + "T" + time + "Z");
```

Comment: _"So I need to add 2 hours to the time variable"_ - or... use the correct time zone? Otherwise actually parsing it may be more robust than doing string manipulation. Have a look at the `java.time` API.

Comment: Is the API expecting **UTC/GMT**?

Comment: Look for java date apis like java.time.ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime classes. They have good apis to add Hours, mins, secs, timezone conversion, etc. it also has formatter, which can convert it to the format you need.

Comment: `Instant.parse(dateTime).plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS).toString()`

Comment: You may try just sending `-02:00` instead of `Z`. This tells the receiver that the time is from a time zone that is 2 hours behind UTC, so they will add the 2 hours for you. Perhaps. It's not so much that it's more convenient, it may also be more correct. Please check that the difference is 2 hours all year, though.

Comment: The Question is unclear, as we have seen in the various comments. Please rewrite to provide clear details as to inputs and outputs, contrasting with your expectations. Best to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your API being called is public, provide a link, or documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any easier way?

Yes, use the modern *java.time* classes.

Apparently you are trying to communicate a moment of 10 AM on that date in UTC. The `Z` in your example code means UTC, pronounced “Zulu”.

To do so, use `OffsetDateTime` with an offset specified by the `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-05-09" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "10:00:00" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Apparently you want to send this value as a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Those formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

You do not explain exactly how or where this 2 hour discrepancy appears. I would guess that you are seeing a result after an adjustment has been made from UTC to some time zone. If so, **you have no problem**.

If two people are telephoning, in time zones two hours apart, if they look up simultaneously to read the current time from the clock on their respective wall, one person will see 10 AM while the other sees 12 noon. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

You can verify this by applying a `ZoneId` for the suspected time zone, to see the wall-clock time value in the resulting `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-click time.
```

Answer (score -1):

This method might give you helpful hints. Output is: 2019-05-09 16:05

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(2);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(localDateTime.format(formatter));
}
```

Comment: From OP's post, it seems that there could be a need for timezone conversion. I have added just to show that if there is a need of timezone conversion, ZonedDateTime could be used.

Comment: But you don't explain anything, and the value of `zdt` is unused, so I ask again, reading everything written in the answer: *What is the point?* --- My first comment wasn't just because I wanted to know, but to tell you the answer is confusing, and that you should *edit* it to clarify! --- Besides, I don't see anything in the question asking for, or even hinting about, the need for timezone conversion.

Comment: removed variable zdt.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* class to use for this Question. The author of this Question is struggling with time-zone adjustment. But `LocalDateTime` lacks any concept of time zone or offset, so it cannot perform the needed adjustment. I don’t like to down-vote, but I must here.

Comment: @BasilBourque where in the question, the user is mentioning about the timezone conversion? The user is just asking about adding 2 hours. Why are you assuming that he is asking about timezone. OP clearly says **the dateTime variable to an API which requires a String with the time and date in it** where is timezone in this? I still did not understand your concept of downvoting.

Comment: @mufeez-shaikh Perhaps you did not notice the `Z` on the end of the string being built in the code snippet in the Question. That is short for UTC, pronounced “Zulu”. It means an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Since the problem presented is a result afterward that appears with a time-of-day two hours later (or earlier, not clear), I deduced that while the input is in UTC the output seen afterward is being adjusted to another time zone, a zone with an offset two hours ahead of UTC (or behind, again the Question is unclear). So your use of `LocalDateTime` is entirely incorrect.

Comment: In short, calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is almost never the right thing to do. Read [the class doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), paying attention to the 3rd paragraph. To represent a moment, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`, never `LocalDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow to learn more. This has been covered many many times already.